# Sigma-algebra generated by a sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I know intuitively that $$\sigma(\sigma(\theta))=\sigma(\theta),$$ where $\theta$ is the class of all open sets in $\mathbb{R}^\mathrm{k}$. But *why?* How can I prove it?

Also, is $\sigma(\sigma(A))=\sigma(A)$ for any set A?

Comment: Maybe you should first try to answer "What is $\sigma(A)$?" and "What is $\sigma(\sigma(A))$?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sigma(A)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $A$; if $A$ is already a $\sigma$-algebra, then it's just $A$ again. Thus, $\sigma(\sigma(A))=\sigma(A)$.

Comment: (+1) Thanks Brian for your contributions to MSE! Thanks to you, I aced my topology class :)

Comment: @Learner: That's great to hear! You're most welcome.